# Blob upload/download system in JavaScript web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am trying to build an upload/download file system. I am struggling a bit with finding the proper idiomatic way to upload data read from a file, and then allow the user to download it again.

The backend is correctly storing the data sent from the client, but the issue is: how do I encode, and subsequently decode, the data for the server? Should I use `readAsDataURL`? How do I get back the file with the decoded content to be downloaded to the user's machine after getting the data on the (JavaScript) client?

Thanks